# How to run parrellel tests with RSpec and Watir on a Windows machine?

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir

I am trying to run this watir code in Rspec and also I am trying to run the testcases in parallel. But it runs one after another. Is there anyway I can achieve the parallel run?

```
require 'rspec'
require 'watir'
a=[]
2.times do
  a<<Thread.new do
    describe 'My behaviour' do
      it 'should do something' do
        b = Watir::Browser.new
        b.goto 'www.google.com'
        b.text_field(name: 'q').set 'Rajagopalan'
        b.close
      end
    end
  end
end

a.each(&:join)
```

But if I run the same code without Rspec, it runs in parrellel. For an example, consider the below code

```
require 'rspec'
require 'watir'
a = []
2.times do
  a << Thread.new do
    b = Watir::Browser.new
    b.goto 'www.google.com'
    b.text_field(name: 'q').set 'Rajagopalan'
    b.close
  end
end
a.each(&:join)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code you're not running specs in paraller. You're declaring contexts in parallel.

In other words, calling `it` or `specify` does not execute the test code. The block is being saved, and then executed by rspec runner ([somewhere here I believe](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb#L121)). 
That's why RSpec (for example) can run all the examples in a random order.

So, to have parallel execution - you need to do much more than your example code. See examples of projects that do exactly that in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56083900/299774).

Comment: When you say `context` in parallel you meant to say block of describe in parallel, eh?

Comment: Yeah, essentially you're adding example blocks in parallel, which will be executed later - not necessarily in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Parallel Test gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) or [Parallel Split Test gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_split_test)from a Rake Task.
You can see an example [in this sample code](https://github.com/saucelabs-sample-test-frameworks/Ruby-RSpec-Watir/blob/master/Rakefile).

Comment: Hi Titus, I used Parallel Split Test gem, it is running sequencially and it's reporting that `Process.fork is not supported by this Ruby`. I use Ruby2.6.  Do you have any solution to this problem?

Comment: Oh, right, Windows. Parallel gem doesn't work on Windows because it doesn't support `Process.fork`

Comment: @Rajagopalan if you're limited by Windows, you should look into Docker for windows (You'll need Windows Pro) and get your tests to run in a container.

Comment: But I have use my framework in many machines so this doesn't work @Gijs Paulides

Comment: I can't go into your complete setup, but if it's important that the tests are executed on all the separate machines, then, theoratically, it _should_ be possible to run `rspec` on one machine paralel, and let `watir` connect to the different machines and start up a browser remotely. Big project, much work, not certain it would even work. But that would be the solution if you don't want to set-up Docker on all machines. Good luck!